# Remove last character from C++ string

Tags: c++, string, substring

How can I remove last character from a C++ string?

I tried `st = substr(st.length()-1);` But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want a new string with the last character removed or the same string without the last character ?

Comment: For a MFC Visual C++ CString:  `CString str=CString("Hello world");
  str.Delete(str.GetLength()-1);`

Answer (score 262, accepted):

For a non-mutating version:

```
st = myString.substr(0, myString.size()-1);
```

Comment: @MatthieuM. Your example is confusing, I think that the essence of the question is to modify the original string, in your example you're not modifying the original string, because in your example the original string is called "myString" which gives to the confusion, in the question it is "st". Your code should be: `st = st.substr(0, st.size()-1)`. But it still doesn't look the right way, I think that the proper way is to use the function that is intended for this task, it's called erase() and the code is: `st.erase(st.size()-1)`. This would be called a "mutating version".

Comment: @CzarekTomczak: I understand this is not exactly what was asked for, thus the disclaimer before the actual gist.

Comment: @MattPhillips: his solution is C++11 specific though (`pop_back` did not exist in C++03) and it is also an in-place modification (and the OP never clarified whether he wanted in-place or not)... as such, he has **a** correct answer, but not the only possible one.

Answer (score 582):

Simple solution if you are using C++11. Probably O(1) time as well:

```
st.pop_back();
```

Comment: As a FYI - its being supported only from GCC 4.7 (off course along w/ the -std=c++11 compilation switch)

Comment: Don't forget to check `length()`.

Comment: Would be good to add the most convenient way to remove the last X characters as well.

Comment: @user1382306 most implementation already check for empty-ness

Comment: `The behavior is undefined if the string is empty. ` from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back)

Answer (score 43):

That's all you need:

```
#include <string>  //string::pop_back & string::empty

if (!st.empty())
    st.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 28):

```
if (str.size() > 0)  str.resize(str.size() - 1);
```

An `std::erase` alternative is good, but I like the `- 1` (whether based on a size or end-iterator) - to me, it helps expresses the intent.

BTW - Is there really no `std::string::pop_back`? - seems strange.

Comment: There is no `std::string::pop_back` in C++03; it's been added in C++0x, though.

Comment: OK - thanks. It caused be a bit of confusion - I could swear I've used it, yet it's not there. Maybe I have a non-standard library in some compiler somewhere (between VC++2003, VC++2008, MinGW GCC3 MinGW GCC 4 and Linux GCC 4, you do get a few differences). More likely, I'm just getting confused with other types.

Comment: resize() is probably not intended for such use, it's a memory related function, erase() is for deleting characters.

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak - sorry for the absurdly late reply, but `resize` is a resizing function, and no more a memory function that anything else that might increase the memory needed. For example, if you `resize` to a smaller size, it will *not* reduce the memory reserved. I think you're thinking of `reserve`, which at least *might* reduce memory allocated if asked to - see [resize here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) and [reserve here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/).

Comment: if (!str.empty()) is preferred over size

Answer (score 21):

```
buf.erase(buf.size() - 1);
```

This assumes you know that the string is not empty.  If so, you'll get an `out_of_range` exception.

Comment: buf[buf.size()-1] = '\0'; doesn't remove anything - it just changes the character that was there to have the value zero. std:;strings can happily contain such characters.

Comment: Neil is correct.  I probably should have clarified this in my answer.  The second option will effectively change the value of the last character so it won't print, but the string length will stay the same.  Using erase actually "removes" the last character and will change the size of the string.

Comment: @RC It will print, assuming you use something like cout << buf. How it appears will depend on your platform. And you can always clarify by editing your answer.

Comment: What's much better about `size()`  instead of `end()` of another answer?

Answer (score 19):

`str.erase( str.end()-1 )`

Reference: [std::string::erase() prototype 2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)

no c++11 or c++0x needed.

Comment: This can lead to weird situation: the size of the string had been reduced but the last character is not set to '\0'.

Comment: @Deqing can you give more details of what happens in such case?

Comment: For example if you have `string s("abc");`, after erase it seems working: `cout<<s; // prints "ab"`, however, the last character is still there: `cout<<s[2]; // still prints 'c'`.

Comment: easily fixed: just `str[str.length()-1] = 0; str.erase(str.end()-1);`

Comment: @Dequing: your example is invalid. The erase reduces the size of the string, so the access to `s[2]` is illegal.

Comment: EML is correct. That's why it is important to use c_str() any time you're going to access character by character and expect a \0 terminal. The only correct way to access a std:string otherwise is with an iterator.

Answer (score 14):

```
int main () {

  string str1="123";
  string str2 = str1.substr (0,str1.length()-1);

  cout<<str2; // output: 12

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With C++11, you don't even need the length/size. As long as the string is not empty, you can do the following:

```
if (!st.empty())
  st.erase(std::prev(st.end())); // Erase element referred to by iterator one
                                 // before the end
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.erase(str.begin() + str.size() - 1)`

`str.erase(str.rbegin())` does not compile unfortunately, since `reverse_iterator` cannot be converted to a normal_iterator.

C++11 is your friend in this case.

Comment: This method has problem as well, the last character is not set to '\0'.

Comment: Any particular reason for not doing `str.erase(str.end() - 1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about boundary check or empty string with ternary operator:

`str.erase(str.end() - ((str.length() > 0) ? 1 : 0), str.end());`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string s = "Hello";// Here string length is 5 initially
  s[s.length()-1] = '\0'; //  marking the last char to be null character
  s = &s[0]; // using ampersand infront of the string with index will render a string from the index until null character discovered
  cout<<"the new length of the string "<<s + " is " <<s.length();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -8):

If the length is non zero, you can also

```
str[str.length() - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Setting the last character to `\0` does not change the length of the string. `str.length()` will be inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. We are considering C++. You are correct, it does not change the length of the string