# How do you reverse the order of words (not the letters) in a string?

Tags: c++

How would I go about reversing the order of words in a string? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
string sen = "Go over there";
reverse(sen.begin(), sen.end());
```

But this reverses the entire string but doesn't keep the words in the right order. How do I only reverse the order of words in the string?

Comment: You should reverse one more time each word split by spaces.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: tips: split to words into vectors then print any orders as you want!

Comment: _I tried this but it doesn't work:_ There is absolutely no reason why that **should** work. Surely not enough research.

Comment: Just noticed `(not the letters)` in the title. I deleted my answer and edited the question.

Comment: @JesseGood - Possible, but that question was doing it with char arrays, rather than the C++ string type.  Still algorithmically applicable, but not necessarily API applicable.

Comment: @remyabel - try out my code below, it uses the same API you do (i.e. the C++ string object), and attempts to use those relevant APIs.  Im personally a bit rusty on my C++ but the algorithm should be correct.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I modified my answer. It (ab)uses the standard library but is rather verbose.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: If you look at most of the answers, they use and suggest `std::string`. The C++ way is already [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17026996/906773).

Comment: @JesseGood - Also a good catch, one could get around this by "using namespace std;"  Also a good find finding a related post :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear: the title and the contenta disagree with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I have written many string functions like this before:

```
// Make copy of this original if you don't wish to destroy in the process
string sen    = "Go over there";

// string that will become your reversed string
string newStr = new string();

// A temp variable that will hold the current position of the last separator character
int aChar     = -1;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// You may want to delete pre and post spaces here
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Loop through the entire string until the original is empty
while(sen.length > 0){
    // Find the last separator character (in your case a space) within the string
    aChar   = sen.find_last_of(" ");

    // Append the word created from one char forward of the last found separator char
    // to the end of the CURRENT version of the original string
    newStr += sen.substr(aChar + 1, sen.length - aChar - 1);

    // Store a new version of the original string that is the SUBSTRING from beginning (char 0)
    // to one char before the last found separator character
    sen     = sen.substr(0, aChar - 1);

    // Need to add the space between the words, but only if the new substring is not empty
    if(sen.length > 0) newStr += " ";
}
```

I have not tested this code, but if the APIs work the way they are intended, algorithmically this should work.

As an API this might look like follows

```
string reverse(string inStr){
    // Make copy of the original so we don't destroy it in the process
    string sen    = inStr.copy();

    // string that will become your reversed string
    string newStr();

    // A temp variable that will hold the current position of the last separator character
    int aChar     = -1;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // You may want to delete pre and post spaces here
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Loop through the entire string until the original is empty
    while(sen.length > 0){
        // Find the last separator character (in your case a space) within the string
        aChar   = sen.find_last_of(" ");

        // Append the word created from one char forward of the last found separator char
        // to the end of the CURRENT version of the original string
        newStr += sen.substr(aChar + 1, sen.length - aChar - 1);

        // Store a new version of the original string that is the SUBSTRING from beginning
        // (char 0) to one char before the last found separator character
        sen     = sen.substr(0, aChar - 1);

        // Need to add the space between the words, but only if the new substring is not empty
        if(sen.length > 0) newStr += " ";
    }

    return newStr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string sen = "Go over there";
    string rev = reverse(sen);
}
```

Comment: `new`?  Is this java?

Comment: @Yakk - good catch, thanks :-)  I had said above how my C++ is a bit rusty LOL

Answer (score 0):

If the words inside the string are separated by spaces, you can use `string.find()` inside a `while` loop to locate the breaks, and then use `string.substr()` to output the words to a `vector`. Then you can simply read the `vector` backwards.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf6f951cb249c8b)

If you use C++11, `sen.pop_back()` gets rid of the last space, otherwise you can check out [Remove last character from C++ string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310939/remove-last-character-from-c-string) for other examples. Secondly, instead of doing `std::reverse(output.begin(), output.end())`, we just use the reverse iterators `rbegin()` and `rend()`. The for loop could be improved definitely, but it does the job.

```
#include <sstream> 
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::string sen = "Go over there";
    std::string word = "";
    unsigned int len = 0;
    for (const auto& c : sen) {
        ++len;
        if (c == ' ' || len == sen.size()) {
            if (len == sen.size())
                word += c;
            output.push_back(word);
            word = "";
        }
        if (c != ' ')
            word += c;
    }
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(output.rbegin(), output.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss, " "));
    sen = oss.str();
    sen.pop_back(); // Get rid of last space, C++11 only
    std::cout << sen;
}
```